# Two versions of same software on a system

Tags: wix

I have created a Installer for my product in WIX.
The requirement was that, user should be able to install two different versions of the product on their machine.

I have modified the Upgrade code for another version, so that previous version does not gets uninstalled when the newer one is installed.
I have also changed the names of the shortcuts that are created on Desktop and in Start menu.

Now my question is that whether I need to change the Product Code also?
Do I need to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you also need to change the ProductCode.

The correct approach for supporting side by side installations is to use the same UpgradeCode for all versions. After that you can remove the upgrade rule which prevents downgrades and modify the rule which automatically uninstalls older versions.

As a side note, each version should use a unique install path.

Comment: I agree the ProductCode must be changed, yet I think in this situation UpgradeCode should also be different for each product. Otherwise products will be considered related.

Comment: When I install only one version of the software, the uninstall works perfectly fine. But when both the versions of the softwares are installed, If I uninstall one of them, the shortcuts for the version being uninstalled are not removed. Is it because the component GUID for the shortcuts is same. Also the shortcut registry that I specified is same for both.

Comment: Had exact the same problem as The King commented. Spent 3 days on it actually. Thank you. The King.